# C++ and DirectX I can see right through models and the world as if it was all transparent?

Tags: c++, directx

The issue is that I can see through models and the world and see whats on the other side. When I look at the terrain I can see if there is anything through a mountain on the otherside and so on. This has happened before but I fixed it and don't remember how. Any way to fix this?

Comment: It sounds like your normal vectors are inverted.

Comment: hmm.. well I'm using vertices and indicies to make a world from a heightmap. How would I flip the normals on that? (Sorry I'm kinda nooby)

Comment: i am noob can you tell which transformations did you use?

Comment: do you mean the matrix i used?

Comment: Reverse the order you draw your triangles.  They should be specified in counter-clockwise order.

Comment: You enabled depth testing, right . . . ?

Comment: depth testing? and how do i reverse the order I drew the triangles in?

Comment: Can you make your source code available somehow? This is like fishing without knowing that there are actually fish in the pond...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to fix the [winding direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Winding_Direction_and_Leading_Vertex_Positions) of your vertices. If you have them reversed by accident and backface culling is enabled, then you will see through these triangles. Winding direction is set as a `BOOL` in [D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s `FrontCounterClockwise` member, and culling in its `CullMode` ([`D3D11_CULL_MODE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476108%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) member

***Update:*** You may also have depth testing disabled, (which if disabled, would require you to draw furthest objects first, otherwise further items will draw over nearer ones already rendered ("painters algorithm")). Make sure you have depth testing enabled in your depth stencil state ([D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) when you [create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476506%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it.