# SharpDX Toolkit models rendering inside out

Tags: c#, sharpdx

A little while ago I decided to switch from XNA to SharpDX Toolkit as it is actively being supported and is quite similar to XNA. While I've had no trouble at all with creating 2D games I decided to attempt a basic 3D game. I can get both the model and it's texture to load but when it renders it only shows the texture on the side facing away from the camera doesn't show anything at all in between.

This is the code I am using to set up the environment.

```
    Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, -10f * 2.5f);
    Vector3 cameraTarget = Vector3.Zero;

    BoundingSphere modelBounds = model.CalculateBounds();

    float fovAngle = MathUtil.DegreesToRadians(45);
    float aspectRatio = (float)GraphicsDevice.BackBuffer.Width / GraphicsDevice.BackBuffer.Height;
    float near = 0.01f;
    float far = 100f;
    float scaling = 10f / modelBounds.Radius;

    Matrix translation = Matrix.Scaling(scaling) * Matrix.RotationY((float)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds) * Matrix.Translation(0, -modelBounds.Center.Y * scaling, 0);
    Matrix lookAt = Matrix.LookAtLH(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, Vector3.Up);
    Matrix projection = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(.9f, aspectRatio, near, far);
```

And this is the code that renders it.

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        model.Draw(GraphicsDevice, translation, lookAt, projection);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Any help that could be given is appreciated.

Comment: Note that this sort of behavior arises when the surface normals are inverted; back face culling is hiding the front faces instead, and the back faces are shown instead of culled.

Comment: The normals can be flipped if the polys wind in the wrong direction.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895289/c-and-directx-i-can-see-right-through-models-and-the-world-as-if-it-was-all-tr for explanations and fixes.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.